# Add OnTouchListener to each TextView in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, textview, ontouchlistener

I've implemented an OnTouchListener for my GridView so that I may detect if the user touched a TextView and if so I change its shape, then upon release it's supposed to reset the shape to the original. It works, except in one case. If I touch down on a TextView then drag the finger to a different TextView and then release, it will reset the shape of the TextView that the finger was over upon release, when I need it to reset the first TextView touched.

To solve the issue I would like to add an OnTouchListener to each TextView instead of the entire GridView. Then I can be sure upon release the shape gets reset. How do you do that though, there is no OnItemTouchListerner I can apply to the GridView. (I can't use OnItemClickListener because I'm already using that and it needs to be called on touch down not just click.)

If you just can't do that, how can I fix this code to ensure the shape will always be reset on touch release even if the touch is released somewhere else on screen? It should be reset as soon as the finger leaves the bounds of the touched TextView.

```
gridView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        float currentXPosition = event.getX();
        float currentYPosition = event.getY();
        int position = gridView.pointToPosition((int) currentXPosition, (int) currentYPosition);

        //get real position, because of item reuse position might not be the correct position
        int firstPosition = gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int childPosition = position - firstPosition;

        if (gridView.getChildAt(childPosition) != null) {
            TextView touchedTextView = (TextView)gridView.getChildAt(childPosition);

            int action = event.getActionMasked();

            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Log.d("test", "touch down");
                touchedTextView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_shape_active));
                }
            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                Log.d("test", "touch released"); 
                touchedTextView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_shape));
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Make `touchedTextView` a class member of the `OnTouchListener`, and set it in the `if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)` block.

Comment: Alternatively, you could set an `OnTouchListener` on each `TextView` in the Adapter's `getView()` method.